# generic type that extends interface, my variable returns null unless i cast it to a specific class

Tags: java, android

I have a class that i'm uses a generic Type that extends the interface zwave
everything is fine until i try to access a zwave variable for some reason the rm.keyword gives a "NullPointerException". if I cast it to the class scene it works, but that is not what I want

```
public <T extends zwave> T Find(List<T> Zwave,List<List<String>> listofinputstrings)
{
    for(List<String> lst: listofinputstrings)
    {
        for(String str: lst)
        {

            for (T rm: Zwave)
            {
    //*** problem is here
    //rm.keyword is always gives a NullPointerException unless i cast it to a class
               if (rm.keyword.equals( str.toLowerCase()))
               {
                   return  rm;
               }
            }

        }
    }


    return  null;
}
```

//here is the interface

```
 interface zwave
 {
    public String keyword="";
    public String zwaveID="";
 }
```

//here is a class that implements the interface

```
public class Scene implements zwave
{
   String name;
   String keyword;
   String zwaveID;

    public Scene(String Name,String Keyword,String ZwaveID)
    {
        name= Name;
        zwaveID= ZwaveID;
        keyword = Keyword;
    }
}
```

---

### edit

Working code

//search class

```
public <T extends searchable> T Find(List<T> searchableclasses, List<List<String>> listofinputstrings)
{
    for(List<String> lst: listofinputstrings)
    {
        for(String str: lst)
        {

            for (T searchable: searchableclasses)
            {

                for(String key: searchable.GetKeywords())
                {
                    if ( key.equals(str.toLowerCase()))
                    {
                        return searchable;
                    }
                }
            }

        }
    }


    return  null;
}
```

//abstract class

```
 abstract class searchable
 {
    String[]  keywords; //using array so i can use java's param ability
    public List<String> GetKeywords()
    {
        return new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(keywords));
    }
 }
```

//actual class

```
public class Scene extends searchable
{
   String name;
   String zwaveID;

    public Scene(String Name,String ZwaveID,String... Keywords)
    {
        name= Name;
        zwaveID= ZwaveID;
        keywords = Keywords;
    }
}
```

Comment: rm.keyword is null or empty string as ""?

Comment: How do you know it's null? Are you getting a NullPointerException? What actually happens, when you cast it and when you don't?

Comment: Your example would have been easier to debug if you used the Java convention of starting type names (such as `ZWave`) with capitals.

Comment: Please do NOT use the same names for the fields in the implementing class as you've used for the constants defined in the interface.  That is just asking everyone who ever looks at the code to get horribly confused.

Comment: The problem you describe is impossible. Casting doesn't magically change the value from `null` to something else.

Comment: updated post.   I'm coming from c# and this is one of my first java apps. Also, I need to look at the cosmetic changes people have mentioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't wanna cast you can do some thing like this:

```
public <T extends zwave> T Find(List<T> Zwave,List<List<String>> listofinputstrings)
{

for(List<String> lst: listofinputstrings)
{
    for(String str: lst)
    {
        for (T rm: Zwave)
        {
    if(rm instanceof Scene){
        Method method=null;
        try {
             method = rm.getClass().getMethod("getKeyword");
                           if ( method.invoke(rm).equals( str.toLowerCase()))
                           {
                                  return  rm;
                            }
            } catch (Exception e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
            } 

    }


        }

    }
}


return  null;
```

}

**NOte:define getKeyword method in Scene class:**

I can customize it more with the help of java.lang.reflect. You would not even need to use instance of Scene. But I think you can do it yourself. And hope it will help.
use **Reflection API** to call at run time.

Answer (score 1):

You need to be using a getter method. When you say `rm.keyword`, that's referring to a constant (`zwave.keyword`), which is the empty string. When you cast to `Scene`, the compiler sees that it's a field and looks it up instead.

Generally, you should make fields like `name` and `keyword` `private` unless you have a specific reason not to and use getter and setter methods to manipulate them.

Answer (score 0):

The variables defined in the interface are final static public even though you didn't explicitly define. When the variable is final, once the value is assigned you cannot reassign it again.

Since you have defined as empty string ("") it will take that value. But you define the variable again in `Scene` class. So when you cast to Scene object will refer this variable and not the variable in the interface. Otherwise it refers to interface variable.